# how to write test functions for decorators?

Tags: python, python-2.7, testing, python-decorators

```
from __future__ import print_function
    def nonnegative(f):
    def wrapper(xs):
        for x in xs:
            if x < 0:
                raise ValueError("{} < 0".format(x))
        return f(xs)
    return wrapper


    @nonnegative
    def inputs(xs):
        for x in xs:
            print(x)

inputs([1, 2, 3, 4])
inputs([-1])}
```

This is my decorator function. how can i write a test function for it? is there any common way?

Answer (score 2):

Sure ... Just make a (really!) simple function and decorate it and see if it has the proper behavior.

```
import unittest

class TestNonNegative(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        super(TestNonNegative, self).setUp()

        self.fn = nonnegative(lambda x: x)

    def test_raises(self):
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            self.fn([1, 2, 3, -1])

        # doesn't raise with all positive numbers
        expected = [1, 2, 3]
        self.assertEqual(self.fn(expected), expected)
```

If you really wanted to, you could even use a `mock.Mock` instance instead of the lambda function and then make sure that it was never called when raising.